# importScripts is not defined firebase in angular app

Tags: web-applications, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

in firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js

getting error as "importScripts is not defined"

where to include  firebase-messaging-sw.js Js file in angular app ?
 I have included in scripts/firebase-messaging-sw.js .

In index.html

```
        <script src="scripts/firebase-messaging.js"></sc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your index.html, shouldn't you be referencing firebase-messaging-sw.js and not firebase-message.js? Also, I believe firebase-messaging-sw.js needs to be at the root level (no nesting in script directory).  Thus you would have something like the following in index.html...

```
<script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js">
```

The service worker script will be loaded and will then import the Firebase scripts from the Firebase CDN.

Comment: yes..I have added <script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js">
 at root level and also  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script> included  these two lines in index.html  but still getting that error import scripts are not defined.  earlier service worker is  not registering  by  <script src="firebase-messaging-sw.js"> adding this script level at root level  now service worker is working and able to register.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. To all other guys don't get confused. If you are on localhost keep it in the root like /htdocs/firebase-messaging-sw.js or /www/firebase-messaging-sw.js this way you have to place this file into the root.